# How to do location based query with simple Django filter?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I've saved user's coordinates in the `User` model. Post model has `latitude`, `longitude` and `radius` field. Only the users in that vicinity(of Post) will be able to see that post. I don't know how to use `filter()` here so I used the following approach:

```
post=Posts.objects.all()
for a in post:
    distance= geopy.distance.geodesic((lat1,lng1), (a.latitude, a.longitude)).km
    print(distance)
    if distance < a.radius:
        p.append(a)    
    else:
        continue
```

Here, `lat1` and `lng1` are the coordinates of current `User`. Suggest if there is any better way as this seems very inefficient.

Comment: You can work with [*GeoDjango*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/) queries if you use a PostGIS or SpatiaLite database.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I can but it's a lot of hassle for just one simple query that I want to make. I'm pretty sure there has to be a simple way to get this done.

Comment: well internally often such databases work with a [spatial k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) to index data. This makes lookup often take *O(log n)* over a linear approach.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem PostGIS it is then. Thank you. I'll keep it open in case somebody has a unique approach for this.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements, you could use a square instead of a circle. Pre-calculate the x-max, x-min, y-max and y-min boundaries for your square and then do a simple `User.filter(lat__gt=lat_min, user.lng__gt=lng_min, user.lat__lt=lat_max ...` lookup in the database.

In a past project, I used this:

```
def get_latlng_bounderies(lat, lng, distance):
    """
    Return min/max lat/lng values for a distance around a latlng.
    :lat:, :lng: the center of the area.
    :distance: in km, the "radius" around the center point.
    :returns: Two corner points of a square that countains the circle,
              lat_min, lng_min, lat_max, lng_max.
    """
    gc = great_circle(kilometers=distance)
    p0 = gc.destination((lat, lng), 0)
    p90 = gc.destination((lat, lng), 90)
    p180 = gc.destination((lat, lng), 180)
    p270 = gc.destination((lat, lng), 270)

    ret = p180[0], p270[1], p0[0], p90[1]
    return ret
```

Its not a circle, so its not exact around the "corners" of the square, but its much faster, because its a simple float comparision in the database.

Comment: That is very smart way around this problem. I'll analyse my requirements and maybe I'll use this. Thank you for such a great answer.